# RSS feed for SO Blog

Tags: support, feed, blog

I've finally decided to set up an RSS feed for the few blogs I frequent.  I'm using IE 8, and so went to 'Coding Horror' and hit the orange button and then subscribed.  When I went to the StackOverflow Blog, and hit the orange button, I just got an error page.

Any input on how to make this work (I'd prefer not to have to get a separate tool for the few RSS feeds I plan on watching)?

Error: 'Internet Explorer cannot display this feed'

**Edit:**  For reasons I can't determine (the SO Team says nothing changed), I was now able to add the feed as normal.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is this "Bloy"?  Am I missing out on the newest blag-o-tube slang?

Comment: Not sure what happened, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of clicking the orange button, try the following, which just worked for me in IE8 (Win7):

- Click the "[Complete](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/index.php/feed/)" link under "RSS" on blog.stackoverflow.com.
- When it comes up, you'll see an option to subscribe in the main window, near the top, in a big yellow box. (Note: Once you complete these steps, that option goes away, since you're already subscribed.)
- Click that option. You're subscribed.

Comment: When I click on 'Complete' I just get a page of XML and no box up top or anything happening at all.

Comment: On IE 8? I wonder if I have an add-in installed that I don't know about.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the actual url for the complete SO Blog feed:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/index.php/feed/

I don't see why you shouldn't be able to subscribe using that URL.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to manually add a feed in IE, I'll probably have to ask a SU question on it.  When I go to that link, I get the same XML page I mentioned in the comment on John's question.